# Error: Could not find or load main class com.ibm.cics.wsdl.ls2ws.ls2ws

Tags: web-services, cics

I am getting below error while submitting JCL with CICS web service assistance tool - DFHLS2WS, can someone please help to share sample JCL used for CICS webservices?
Also, please suggest how the error can be resolved?

```
cd: /usr/lpp/cicsts//lib/wsdl/DFHLS2WS 33: /usr/lpp/cicsts//home/ka7a/KA7A/lib/w
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.6.31 - pmz3180sr6fp31-20210510_01(SR6
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 z/OS s390-31-Bit 20210423_470221 (JIT enabled, A
OpenJ9   - 19b42fd
OMR      - a028c6b
IBM      - 8165371)
JCL - 20210422_01 based on Oracle jdk8u291-b09
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ibm.cics.wsdl.ls2ws.ls2ws
```

Thanks, Ravindra.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an incorrect value specified for the parameter 'USSDIR', which typically does not need to be set, but if you do set it then the value will be appended to '/usr/lpp/cicsts/' to specify the CICS TS directory in the UNIX system services file system.

You can find a simple example in the doc here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.3?topic=assistant-dfhls2ws-high-level-language-wsdl-conversion
(scroll to the bottom of the page).